# Android Studio installation error in w7

Tags: android-studio-3.0

This stuff is not downloading, can I manually download and add to Android studio?

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip

[Error in Android Studio downloading and installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59tSw.png)

Comment: its not error android sdk files ,required component u have to download

Comment: But its not downloading....I have spend several hours but not finished. So I quit.

Comment: may be u r net speed is slow